# Все необходимые действия для отправки смс напрямую из приложения для Android API 21

Tags: android, sms

Я пытаюсь сделать приложение, отправляющее SMS-сообщение. Находил много статей и вопросов на stackoverflow, но по-прежнему приложение не отправляет sms, а в logcat вообще никаких сообщений. Пожалуйста, укажите все необходимые действия для того чтобы отправить сообщение напрямую из приложения (не вызывая стороннее).

Что уже сделано (использую код из [этого](https://github.com/shinobicontrols/bitesize-kitkat/tree/master/MessageMe) туториала).

В манифесте:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
              android:required="true"/>

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
            android:name="com.shinobicontrols.messageme.ConversationListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
            android:name="com.shinobicontrols.messageme.ConversationDetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_conversation_detail"
            android:parentActivityName="com.shinobicontrols.messageme.ConversationListActivity" >
        <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.shinobicontrols.messageme.ConversationListActivity" />
    </activity>

    <!-- BroadcastReceiver that listens to incoming SMS messages -->
    <receiver
            android:name="com.shinobicontrols.messageme.receivers.SMSBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- BroadcastReceiver that listens to incoming MMS messages -->
    <receiver
            android:name="com.shinobicontrols.messageme.receivers.MMSBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- Activity for composing SMS/MMS messages -->
    <activity
            android:name="com.shinobicontrols.messageme.ComposeSMSActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_compose_sms" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
            <data android:scheme="mms" />
            <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Service that delivers messages for "Quick Response" -->
    <service
            android:name="com.shinobicontrols.messageme.HeadlessSmsSendService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
            <data android:scheme="mms" />
            <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

Код для кнопки отправки сообщения:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                String recipient = ((TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.composeEditTextTo)).getText().toString();
                String message   = ((TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.composeEditTextMessage)).getText().toString();

                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(recipient, null, message, null, null);
            }
```

В настройках выбрал его как дефолтное СМС-приложение.

Телефон ASUS Zenfone Laser(ASUS_Z00RD), Android 5.0.2, API 21. 
Двухсимочный, но стоит только одна сим-карта. Денег для отправки достаточно.

Comment: Попробуйте выудить к примеру через `Toast` побольше информации. Очень интересно поведение блока с `smsManager`. И неплохо было бы его в `try catch` обернуть.

Comment: @Serodv а что конкретно выводить и каким образом информацию получить? Опыта в android sdk у меня очень мало.

Comment: `try{
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(recipient, null, message, null, null);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }`

Comment: @Serodv никаких ошибок тут не происходит

Comment: Значит собака порылась где-то раньше

Comment: @Serodv да, я уже сам разобрался. Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка оказалась в вводе номера телефона. Номер телефона надо писать не через "+7", а через "8". Однако странно, что я не получал сообщение о некорректности номера (что происходило по крайней мере в случае пустой строки вместо номера), возможно, "+" стирается. Надеюсь, что человек на Маршалловых Островах простит мне три дня спама словом "test":)

Comment: Человеческий фактор, как обычно